# Can you checkout git revision into new directory?

Tags: git

Say I have a git repository clone at:

```
/myrepos/foo
```

so there is a `.git` directory here:

```
/myrepos/foo/.git
```

and say I want to create a new directory at:

```
/tmp/bar
```

with a copy of the tree as at revision `123`

Such that:

- the `/myrepos/foo` directory (nor its `.git` directory) is **not** modified
- no `/tmp/bar/.git` folder

Is there a command to do that?

Something like:

```
/myrepos/foo$ git checkout --into-new-directory /tmp/bar 123
```

perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do that.

The most straightforward, available since Git 2.5 (but with some important fixes in later versions if you intend to do any *work* with these), is to use `git worktree add`.  This will add a new working tree; you choose where it goes.

The resulting working tree *does*, however, have a `.git` *file*.  You may simply remove this file (`rm /tmp/foo/.git`); to inform your local Git that this working tree is now gone, run `git worktree prune` right afterwards.  The actual checkout will remain in place.  For instance:

```bash
$ git worktree add --detach /tmp/git HEAD~3
[output trimmed]
$ rm /tmp/git/.git
$ git worktree prune
```

If your Git predates 2.5, or for some reason you don't want to use `git worktree`, you can:

- create the directory (`mkdir /tmp/foo`)
- run `(export GIT_INDEX=$(mktemp -u) && git checkout --work-tree=/tmp/foo <hash> && rm $GIT_INDEX)`

in any POSIX-compatible shell.  (Note: untested, unlike the `git worktree add` example.)

Answer (score 1):

Git can manage multiple working trees.  Run this:

```
git worktree add /tmp/foo 123
```

The new folder will have a small `.git` folder but you should be able to remove it.  Run `git worktree help` for a little more info and `git help worktree` for a lot more info.

Comment: Thats interesting, but does that modify the .git folder?  (I just want an ephemeral copy of the tree at a specific revision, not for modification, and to be deleted shortly after.)

Comment: Yes, the original repo keeps track of where all its worktrees are, but you could remove the one you created if you remove its `.git` directory and run `git worktree prune`.

Comment: Hmmm.  I think what I'm after is something like `git archive` but that doesn't pack up the files, and just creates the directory.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: `git archive ... | tar -xf -` works, but note that `git archive` has subtly different effects from `git checkout`, depending on files such as `.gitattributes` in the commit in question.

Answer (score 0):

Git can create an archive file of a specific commit and then you can extract that archive file wherever you would like.

```
git archive --prefix foo/ -o /tmp/foo.tar 123
cd /tmp
tar -xvf foo.tar
```

This shouldn't affect the main repository at all.